# How to store PHP mixed array in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

For example, if I have following array:

```
$arr = array();
$arr['key1'] = 'str1';
$arr['key2'] = 123;
$arr['key3'] = array('key4'=>'str2');
```

How to store it correctly without serializing or json encoding? As I need to search some keys/values and manipulate with it.

Comment: *"[...] without serializing or json encoding?"* - You can't really...  If you want to store a PHP array in a database, you either need to serialize it (`serialize`), convert to JSON (`json_encode`) or normalize your database to have a relationship structure.

Comment: You can search and manipulate json encoded data depending on the database, e.g. MySQL 5.7+

Comment: Store using the most compatible datatype - i.e. string type. If you need to distinguish numeric `123` and string `'123'` then store non-numeric values with wrapping quotes simply.